# Xamarin Ios Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase in my xamarin ios project. FCM token is getting generated, but when I am pushing a notification from firebase console nothing is happening. Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing? I have used packages such as

- Firebase.ios.InstanceID - 2.0.4,
- Firebase.ios.Core - 4.0.8,
- Firebase.ios.CloudMessaging - 2.0.4

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are testing it on a physical device and have all the necessary code in place. **Make sure you have team id added in project setting at FCM console.**